# How to make a button with outline of a dog bone using css?

Tags: css, button, border, unique, outline

I looked for this but couldn't find it. I am making a pet care website and I want to make some of the buttons in the shape of a bone while still functioning like a normal button (hover functions). Instead of a rounded or rectangular shaped button is there any way to make the outline into the shape of a bone?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry if my post is not specific enough, I am new to html and css. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use an image and add hover functions with CSS

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! Hope you have an awesome day @boyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use an image here's an example made only with HTML and CSS.

```css
.bone{
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4{
  background:#fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
}
.c1{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.c2{
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.c3{
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.c4{
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.b1 {
  background:#fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  position:absolute;  
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}
.b2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="bone">
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c3"></div>
    <div class="c4"></div>
    <div class="b1">
      <div class="b2">
        Button Text
      </div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This is awesome--- exactly what I was looking for.